# Why my python subclass doesn't recognize attribute from super class?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, attributes, super

I was testing inheritance of python, I've got this:

```
__metaclass__=type
class b:
    def __init__(s):
        s.hungry=True
    def eat(s):
        if(s.hungry):
            print "I'm hungry"
        else:
            print "I'm not hungry"
class d(b):
    def __init__(s):
        super(b,s).__init__()
    def __mysec__(s):
        print "secret!"

obj=d()
obj.eat()
```

There's runtime error as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "2.py", line 17, in ?
    obj.eat()
  File "2.py", line 6, in eat
    if(s.hungry):
AttributeError: 'd' object has no attribute 'hungry'
```

I couldn't understand this, as the super class of "b" has s.hungry in its **init**, and the sub class calls "super" inside its own "**init**"
Why still, python says "d" object has not attribute 'hungry'?

Another confusion: the error message treats "d" as an object, but I defined it as a class!
Did I get anything wrong, how to make it work?

Comment: Use `super` on the current class, not the parent class. i.e. `super(d, s).__init__()`

Comment: Also, I highly recommend against using one-letter names in Python. I suggest reading through https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: super() in python3 is much simple, you do not need pass args.

Comment: A class is an object, a class instance of an object. Why are you overriding dunder init in ```d```?  -just remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class d(b):
    def __init__(s):
        super(d,s).__init__()
    def __mysec__(s):
        print ("secret!")
```

[Document](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super):

> For both use cases, a typical superclass call looks like this:

```
> class C(B):
>     def method(self, arg):
>         super(C, self).method(arg)
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is what you were looking for:

```
__metaclass__=type
class b:
    def __init__(self):
        self.hungry=True
    def eat(self):
        if(self.hungry):
            print "I'm hungry"
        else:
            print "I'm not hungry"
class d(b):
    def __init__(self):
        super(d,self).__init__()
    def __mysec__(self):
        print "secret!"

obj=d()
obj.eat()
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to write the code for more clarity in python 3.x

```py
class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        self.hungry=True

    def eat(self):
        if(self.hungry):
            print("I'm hungry")
        else:
            print("I'm not hungry")

class Derived(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() # this works
        # super(Derived,self).__init__() # this works
        # super(Base,self).__init__() # this doesn't work

>>> d=Derived()
>>> d.eat()
I'm hungry
```